# Simple universal Visual Studio 2017 project template for Web

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, typescript, web

I'm developing simple websites in Visual Studio with external tools like angular cli or webpack.

It doesn't seem as if there is an appropriate project template for that. I don't need special things like the nodejs or asp .net project provides. I just want to be able to define my own actions, nothing else.

---

What I want:

- Simple project structure showing files (just like normal but without listing npm packages)
- Configurations such as Debug/Release
- Run own scripts on build/rebuild/start etc. (depending on configurations)

I know that this could be accomplished using vs code. But vs2017 offers much functionality that I need.

---

Is there a way i can accomplish this in VS2017?

If not, would it be possible to write an own project template for that?